Name of an SF teleportation story from 60’s or early 70’s
I read this story in an anthology years ago. A human expedition lands on a planet to meet a new race. The aliens are humanoid, and can teleport. Thinking the Earthlings are hostile, they keep killing expedition members with arrows. The solution to the problem was to trick an alien into the space ship and lift off beyond his teleportation range. Once the alien sees himself too far from the ground, the humans are able to show they aren’t hostile. It may have been written by Poul Anderson or Frederik Pohl.

This seems very familiar.  Searching...

... Not a Prison Make by Joseph Martino.
I read it in the September 1966 Analog but it also been anthologised several times. You can read that issue here, but note that it's a 90MB download.
Earth needs to set up a military base on the planet Kanth, but the natives initially regarded the Terrans as enemies and kept teleporting close up and shooting them with crossbows. The solution was:

"Once we understood the situa­tion, we simply flew over their vil­lages and broadcast to them that if they didn't let us alone, we'd sup­ply weapons and instructors to their most deadly enemies. That was the stick. For the carrot, we recognized that in their chaotic situation, they would be willing to follow anyone who could offer them protection from each other. We offered them that protection, if they would help us in enforcing it. That's where you come in. They quickly saw the good sense of our offer, and came to terms. The only problem was to prevent ourselves from being robbed blind by teleporting thieves, and we solved that by sealing all the buildings, putting on double­ door air locks, and flooding them with anesthetic."
"But, blast it, General, you still haven't told me ... "
"How we managed to hold a con­scious prisoner? That turned out to be fairly simple. We realized that their teleporting range had to be limited, since it was we who found them, not vice versa. So we loaded our unconscious captives into a scout cruiser, and took them several planetary diameters off-world. It turned out we guessed right the first time, and we had them far enough out they couldn't teleport back. When they realized they weren't going anywhere, we had no further trouble with them. They were model prisoners."

